# Registration of gitlab-ci runner fails when tags are given

Tags: ruby, database, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

We are encountering an error while registering a gitlab-ci runner *when we specify* tags. Without tags the runner is registered successfully. Gitlab logs show that there is an error with a database table (see complete logs below).

**Error from Gitlab logs**

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'taggings_count' in 'field list': UPDATE 'tags' SET 'taggings_count' = COALESCE('taggings_count', 0) + 1 WHERE 'tags'.'id' = 8
```

From the logs we assume that some bundler package uses a wrong table (`tags` instead of `ci_tags`).

Is there anybody out there who has any idea on how to solve this or what is causing the problem?

Results of GitLab application and GitLab environment info are all fine without an error.

**This is how we register the runner**

```
#> gitlab-ci-multi-runner --debug register
Runtime platform                                arch=amd64 os=linux
revision=f896af7 version=1.7.1
Checking runtime mode                           GOOS=linux uid=0
Running in system-mode.                            

Please enter the gitlab-ci coordinator URL (e.g. https://gitlab.com/):
  https://git.example.org/ci
Please enter the gitlab-ci token for this runner:
  WxbnEs4xTB7paS31401jasdxX
Please enter the gitlab-ci description for this runner:
  [dev-runner-machine]: docker-ci
Please enter the gitlab-ci tags for this runner (comma separated):
  docker
Trying to load /etc/gitlab-runner/certs/git.example.org.crt ... 

Dialing: tcp git.example.org:443 ...                 
ERROR: Registering runner... failed        
  runner=WxbnEs4x status=500 Internal Server Error
PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems
```

**Relevant logs**

```
Started POST "/ci/api/v1/runners/register.json" for 10.6.9.205 at 2016-11-08 10:15:59 +0100

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'taggings_count' in 'field list': UPDATE 'tags' SET 'taggings_count' = COALESCE('taggings_count', 0) + 1 WHERE 'tags'.'id' = 8):
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:309:in 'query'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:309:in 'block in execute'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:484:in 'block in log'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in 'instrument'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:478:in 'log'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:309:in 'execute'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:231:in 'execute'
/home/git/gitlab/config/initializers/connection_fix.rb:20:in 'execute'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:252:in 'exec_delete'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:114:in 'update'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in 'update'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:345:in 'update_all'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb:84:in 'update_counters'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:170:in 'update_counters'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb:104:in 'increment_counter'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb:70:in 'increment_counter'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb:39:in 'block in increment_counters'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb:51:in 'with_cache_name'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb:39:in 'increment_counters'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb:143:in 'block in _create_record'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb:170:in 'block in each_counter_cached_associations'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb:169:in 'each'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb:169:in 'each_counter_cached_associations'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb:141:in '_create_record'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:75:in '_create_record'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:133:in '_create_record'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in 'block in _create_record'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in '__run_callbacks__'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in '_run_create_callbacks'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in '_create_record'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in '_create_record'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:504:in 'create_or_update'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in 'block in create_or_update'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in 'block (2 levels) in compile'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in '__run_callbacks__'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in '_run_save_callbacks'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in 'create_or_update'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:142:in 'save!'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in 'save!'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in 'save!'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in 'block in save!'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:351:in 'block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in 'transaction'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in 'transaction'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in 'with_transaction_returning_status'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in 'save!'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:39:in 'insert_record'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:495:in 'block (2 levels) in _create_record'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:408:in 'replace_on_target'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:403:in 'add_to_target'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:493:in 'block in _create_record'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:183:in 'block in transaction'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in 'transaction'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in 'transaction'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:182:in 'transaction'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:492:in '_create_record'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:187:in '_create_record'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:157:in 'create!'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:306:in 'create!'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-3.5.0/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable/core.rb:415:in 'block (2 levels) in save_tags'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-3.5.0/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable/core.rb:414:in 'each'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-3.5.0/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable/core.rb:414:in 'block in save_tags'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-3.5.0/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable/core.rb:373:in 'each'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-3.5.0/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable/core.rb:373:in 'save_tags'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in 'block in make_lambda'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:228:in 'block in halting_and_conditional'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in 'block in call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in 'each'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in '__run_callbacks__'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in '_run_save_callbacks'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in 'create_or_update'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:120:in 'save'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:37:in 'save'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in 'save'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286:in 'block (2 levels) in save'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:351:in 'block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in 'transaction'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in 'transaction'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in 'with_transaction_returning_status'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286:in 'block in save'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:301:in 'rollback_active_record_state!'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:285:in 'save'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:62:in 'insert_record'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:495:in 'block (2 levels) in _create_record'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:408:in 'replace_on_target'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:403:in 'add_to_target'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:493:in 'block in _create_record'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:183:in 'block in transaction'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in 'block in transaction'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in 'within_new_transaction'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in 'transaction'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in 'transaction'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:182:in 'transaction'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:492:in '_create_record'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:187:in '_create_record'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:153:in 'create'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:290:in 'create'
/home/git/gitlab/lib/ci/api/runners.rb:41:in 'block (2 levels) in <class:Runners>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/grape-0.15.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:66:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/grape-0.15.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:66:in 'block (2 levels) in generate_api_method'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in 'instrument'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/grape-0.15.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:65:in 'block in generate_api_method'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/grape-0.15.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:249:in 'block in run'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in 'instrument'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/grape-0.15.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:230:in 'run'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/grape-0.15.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:300:in 'block in build_stack'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/grape-0.15.0/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:30:in 'call!'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/grape-0.15.0/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:23:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/grape-0.15.0/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:30:in 'call!'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/grape-0.15.0/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:23:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-oauth2-1.2.3/lib/rack/oauth2/server/resource.rb:20:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-oauth2-1.2.3/lib/rack/oauth2/server/resource/bearer.rb:8:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/grape-0.15.0/lib/grape/middleware/error.rb:29:in 'block in call!'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/grape-0.15.0/lib/grape/middleware/error.rb:28:in 'catch'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/grape-0.15.0/lib/grape/middleware/error.rb:28:in 'call!'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/grape-0.15.0/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:23:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/grape-0.15.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:214:in 'call!'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/grape-0.15.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:208:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in 'block in call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in 'block in recognize'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:68:in 'optimized_each'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95:in 'recognize'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/grape-0.15.0/lib/grape/api.rb:101:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/grape-0.15.0/lib/grape/api.rb:43:in 'call!'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/grape-0.15.0/lib/grape/api.rb:38:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:51:in 'serve'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in 'block in serve'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in 'each'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in 'serve'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/omniauth-1.3.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in 'call!'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/omniauth-1.3.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/lib/gitlab/request_profiler/middleware.rb:15:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:16:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.6/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in 'block in call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.6/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in 'catch'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.6/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-cors-0.4.0/lib/rack/cors.rb:80:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-attack-4.3.1/lib/rack/attack.rb:106:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in 'context'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in 'block in call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in '__run_callbacks__'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in '_run_call_callbacks'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in 'run_callbacks'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in 'call_app'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in 'block in call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in 'block in tagged'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in 'tagged'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in 'tagged'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/request_store-1.3.1/lib/request_store/middleware.rb:9:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sentry-raven-1.1.0/lib/raven/integrations/rack.rb:53:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in 'public_send'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in 'method_missing'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:66:in 'block in call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in 'each'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in 'call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:580:in 'process_client'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-worker-killer-0.4.4/lib/unicorn/worker_killer.rb:52:in 'process_client'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:674:in 'worker_loop'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:529:in 'spawn_missing_workers'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:540:in 'maintain_worker_count'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:294:in 'join'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in '<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/unicorn_rails:22:in 'load'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/unicorn_rails:22:in '<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in 'load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in 'kernel_load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in 'run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:332:in 'exec'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in 'run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in 'invoke_command'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in 'dispatch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in 'dispatch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in 'start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in 'start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.2/exe/bundle:34:in 'block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:100:in 'with_friendly_errors'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.2/exe/bundle:26:in '<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in 'load'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in '<main>'
```

System information

```
System:          Debian 8.5
Ruby Version:    2.3.1p112
Gem Version:     2.6.7
Bundler Version: 1.13.2
Rake Version:    10.5.0
Sidekiq Version: 4.1.4

GitLab Version:  8.11.8, Revision 7d593a4
GitLab Shell Version:  3.4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

GitLab 8.11 came out in August but Runner 1.7 came out in late October. Have you tried downgrading the Runner to 1.6 or upgrading GitLab? This seems like it might be caused by running incompatible versions of Runner/GitLab.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to this, very good point. I use version [1.7.1](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/tags/v1.7.1). I will first try to downgrade to version [1.6.1](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/tags/v1.6.1) or even [1.5.3](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/tags/v1.5.3)

Answer (score 1):

This also happened on my installation when I was on Gitlab 8.11, the issue disappeared once I upgraded Gitlab to the latest version. I confirm there is no issue on GitLab 8.13.2.

So I guess a better solution would be to upgrade your Gitlab instance, rather downgrade a runner.

Cheers